# How to select by date only if field is a timestamp?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql

I have a database field `timestamp without timezone`, that has values like `2015-11-23 14:42:55.278`.

Now I want to find database records with just using the date part `2015-11-13`.

Is that possible?

Ideally using hibernate and spring.

Comment: cast(column as date)

Comment: which database are u connecting to?

Comment: So, you want to have all the records whose date is `2015-11-13`, regardless of the time? Or do you want something else?

Comment: All records of the date, regardless of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the column to a date, e.g:

Postgres specific:

```
the_timestamp_column::date = date '2015-11-13'
```

or  (standard SQL)

```
cast(the_timestamp_column as date) = date '2015-11-13'
```

You can also "reduce" the timestamp to different levels using `date_trunc()`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch only for day 2015-11-13 then you can fetch all records using `between` keyword and by using timestamp of start of day.

`dateField between 2015-11-13:<time_of_beginning_of_day> AND 2015-11-14:<time_of_beginning_of_next_day>`

or

`dateField between 2015-11-13:<time_of_beginning_of_day> AND 2015-11-13:<time_of_end_of_day>`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if is the best way in performace terms, but you may search dates between `2015-11-23 00:00:00.000` and `2015-11-23 23:59:59.999`

Comment: Technically correct because a Postgres timestamp has microsecond precision. But I think you're better of with `'2015-11-23' <= datecol and datecol < '2015-11-24'`, which doesn't depend on `timestamp`'s technical implementation

Comment: You are right. In any case Postgree will do the cast from `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm`

Comment: I prefer this solution (with Andomar's correction) to the accepted answer, because it utilizes the index (assuming there is one) on the column.